# ffmpeg for ios how to decode video and modify contrast

Tags: ios, ffmpeg, video-capture

i'm developing an application for iPad that uses rtsp protocol and decode a video from a remote server using FFmpeg library. I need to modify contrast of video, is possible using ffmpeg?

The second question is: how can i calculate buffer of the video? What buffer ffmpeg is usign by default?

thanks=)

Comment: please state this more clearly, what do you mean how can I calculate buffer of video, you mean for av/sync for instance, sure you could modify contrast but using ffmpeg is probably not the best way, since you have to decode the video to a picture format such as rgb565 for instance its best to manipulate it there.

Comment: ok , i solved editing the method: imageFromAVPicture. For the buffer i mean the frames cached by ffmpeg before show on screen, getting data from a network via rtsp..

Comment: again why cache the frames are you trying to sync audio and video, I am not following you. Can you look at the tutorial here www.streammore.tv